# MVC instrumentation & WebApi attribute routing for Sitecore 7.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, asp.net-apicontroller, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.5

I have been trying to get `WebApi` working with **Sitecore 7.5** (I was able to get the same code working with **7.2**) 
I have left in the config the reference to `MVC 5.1`
and 
I am getting the following exception when I try to access a route mapped with an attribute:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("test/api/Other")]
[Route("{action=Get}")]
public class OtherController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetId()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

> Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: key", ExceptionType:
>   "System.ArgumentNullException", StackTrace: " at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue&
>   value) at
>   Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Dispatcher.NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__0.MoveNext()"

The code that I have in the application start is the following:

```cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ConfigureRoutes);
}

public static void ConfigureRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
}
```

any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Have you added the route prefix ("test/api" in this case) to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in Sitecore?

Comment: yes, I have just tried it to add the route prefix to the IngnoreUrlPrefix, and it is still not working... the funny thing is that the same code is working in a clean 7.2 instance, I think that the new DI Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Dispatcher.NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.SelectController is getting an Object reference error

Comment: I think that the issue it is in the Attribute routing, where is getting and Object reference, the only way to get it working is not using attribute routing but classic routing, I am talking about it in this post: http://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/webapi-attribute-routing-is-not-working-with-sitecore-7-5/

Comment: I have the same problem. Upgraded from Sitecore 7.2 to 7.5 and I get the same error when requesting through web api.

Comment: Do you guys know if this was fixed in the latest 7.5 release?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Sitecore 7.5 they are replacing the default `IHttpControllerSelector` with their own `NamespaceHttpControllerSelector` which doesn't support Attribute Routing.

However, it is possible to workaround this. You have to create your own version of `NamespaceHttpControllerSelector` and patch it into the `initialize` pipeline after this one:

```
Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Pipelines.ServicesWebApiInitializer, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore
```

I have created both a Sitecore package and a NuGet package to do this depending on what you prefer and what your needs are.

- [Sitecore package](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/A/Attribute_Routing_Support.aspx)
- [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krusen.Sitecore.WebApi/)
- [NuGet package (Custom)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krusen.Sitecore.WebApi.Custom/)

The "Custom" package creates the code in your solution, so you can edit it yourself if you have special needs. The Sitecore package and the standard NuGet package just drops my assembly in the bin folder and creates a config file in `App_Config\Include` which patches the `initialize` pipeline.

If you want to look at the code, or read a bit more about the issue, have a look at [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Krusen/Sitecore.WebApi).